# How to output commas in CSV

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

So to output some attributes to a csv, I'm using `stringbuilder` which uses the commas as a natural delimiter for commas.  The problem is when I add a string with commas inside in the string, it's splitting it into separate columns for me.  so for ex

`temp.Append("ab,cd,ef")` is giving me 3 separate columns.  How do I output it as a single column with the commas intact.

it's the result of a capture group

```
match = Regex.Match(amt, "^\"([\\d,]+),(\\d\\d\\d)\"$");
```

and then I did

```
amt = Convert.ToString(match.Groups[1].Value) + Convert.ToString(match.Groups[2].Value);
```

so it takes in something like 123,123,123,123 with an unknown number of commas and I want to output the exact same thing with the last commas replaced by a period.  But it's still coming out as

> 123       123       123       123       123

in separate columns

Comment: you could also replace commas with ; or use a different delimeter

Comment: Anytime I need to work with character delimited anything in .Net, I use [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/), it's 1,000,000 times easier, highly recommend it!

Answer (score 7):

You need to wrap the entry in a quote

```
temp.Append("\"ab,cd,ed\"");
```

**UPDATED AFTER REDITED QUESTION**

From what you are saying you wish to convert `123,445,567,890` to `123,445,567.890`  and you want to the CSV output to work:

You still need to wrap your result in quotes so you need

```
amt = string.Format("\"{0}.{1}\"", match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value);
```

Alternatively you could just replace the last ','

```
amt = new Regex(",(?=\\d{3}\"$)").Replace(x,".");
```

or without the regex.

```
char[] y = amt.ToCharArray();
y[amt.LastIndexOf(",")] = '.';
amt = string(y);
```

Comment: It's nice if you could perhaps also fix the question next time, when you deciphered it :/

Answer (score 0):

```
Fields with embedded commas must be delimited with double-quote characters.
example: "Anytown, WW" (if it is one field) had to be delimited in double quotes because it had an embedded comma.
```

Keep a look [here](http://creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm#FileFormat)